# What is the "automatic cutoff" in scipy.linalg.orth()?

Tags: scipy, orthogonal

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.orth.html

And how can I tune it?
I am getting fewer basis than expected.
Google gives me no obviously useful result on the first few pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`orth`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.orth.html) uses the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).  The definition of `orth` currently lives in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/linalg/decomp_svd.py, and as I write this, the complete code for `orth` (dropping the docstring) is:

```
def orth(A):
    u, s, vh = svd(A, full_matrices=False)
    M, N = A.shape
    eps = numpy.finfo(float).eps
    tol = max(M, N) * numpy.amax(s) * eps
    num = numpy.sum(s > tol, dtype=int)
    Q = u[:, :num]
    return Q
```

The result is that singular values less than `tol` are considered to be 0, and those directions are not considered part of the range of `A`.  `tol` is a *relative* tolerance: it is set to `max(M, N)*eps` times the maximum singular value of `A`, where `eps` is the floating point machine epsilon.

`orth` provides no argument to control how `tol` is computed, but as you can see, the function is only a few lines.  If you want to use a different method for deciding which singular values to ignore, you can use `orth` as a starting point for writing your own function.